# Reading unsigned tiny int from Access97 db

Tags: c#, ms-access-97

I have an ancient Access97 database that contains astronomical data that I would like to use in a telescope's pointing software. The Hour and Minute of Right Ascension are stored as UnsignedTinyInt.

I am assuming UnsignedTinyInt is an unsigned short, or ushort. If I code the following, where "reader" is an OleDbDataReader and fld is the ordinal value. Int16 is the shortest integer available, apparently.

```
select myValue from myTable;

ushort myValue;
myValue = reader.GetInt16(fld);
```

The exact exception is Invalid Cast. There are a number of Get methods available in the OleDbDataReader, including three GetInts. No GetInt works, no matter how I declare myValue.

Comment: `I am assuming UnsignedTinyInt is an unsigned short` That is incorrect. It is a `byte`.

Comment: `No GetInt works` That is because they are designed for  (2 bytes) `short`, (4 bytes) `int` and (8 bytes) `long` - while what you have is a (1 byte) `byte`.

Comment: In future you can call [`object GetValue(int ordinal)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) and inspect the returned object (`myValue.GetType()`) to see what type `OleDbDataReader` considers the field to be, that or [`GetSchemaTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getschematable(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Also there is [this table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320435/info-oledbtype-enumeration-vs--microsoft-access-data-types) to consult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this with:

```
select myValue from myTable;

byte myValue;
myValue = reader.GetByte(fld);
```

Comment: Why `ushort`? It has neither the size of the `byte` field in the dictionary, nor the size of the `int` or `uint` the math would be done on.

Comment: @JonHanna, it worked to get the information I needed.  The unsigned tiny int in the Access97 database system is very tiny, as indicated, and sure you can put it into a byte in your code, but it's smaller than a byte or even uint.  In my final code for the project, all I was doing was storing it as a regular integer in the Sql Server database I created to hold the data I was extracting. I modified my answer here in response to the pressure of users who didn't like my using the ushort. Oh well. By the way, I never finished reading your book, but found it interesting nevertheless. Happy trails!

Comment: `ushort` is a bit of a worse of both worlds compromise. `byte` (or `sbyte` which is the most direct comparison to tiny in Access) has the size advantage, but with any arithmetic or bitwise use it gets promoted to `int` so there's a speed advantage of using that and not bothering to cast back again after operations, so there's advantages in either extreme but not in between. (The book is best read skim-reading the first chapter, its sort of has to get what it gets out of the way, out of the way, but looking back after a few years I'm afraid it starts rather weak).